# Unity XR Grab Interactable not working after changing physics layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a VR project in unity using the VR preset, and i'm following a tutorial on making a gun for it (The video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvvovHdHZhs&t=361s by Valem, in a series). When i change the physics layers to prevent the magazine and gun colliding, it for some reason does not allow me to pick up the gun or magazine. Can anyone help?

I set the layer on the objects to (the newly created layer) XRGrabInteractable (can be anything), and disabled the collision in the physics tab. Even if it's named something else or can collide with its own layer, the issue still appears.

(sorry for the poor wording, i can reiterate if you need it)

Comment: I am using XR Grab Interactable Plugin.
Please share Inspector with XR Grab Interactor (Left & Right) and Gun and Magazines properties.